# Pug to display array from a known value to a key

Tags: arrays, json, gulp, pug, pugjs

Not sure if the title makes sense but what I'm trying to do here is to get Pug to display regions for a specific country from this [country-region-data JSON file](https://github.com/benkeen/country-region-data/blob/master/data.json) but with no success. I do managed to get it to display all countries and its regions but that's not the goal.

Here is my Pug:

```
- var countries = locals['countries']
  each country in countries.countryName == "Singapore"
    each region in country.regions
      option= region.name
```

I'm still new to Pug and JSON. As you can see from the JSON file, `countryName` is a key and `Singapore` is a value to a key (is the terms here correct?)

I really wish someone could shed some light!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the solution!

```
select.form-control(id="address_state")
  - var states = locals['countries']
    each val, key in countries
      if val.countryName == 'Malaysia'
        each region, key in val.regions
          option= region.name
```